# save my value in one activity and show this value into different activity

Tags: android

I try to save my password into an activity & i would like to recover it into different activity but when my application launch the second activity, it crash.
someone can help me?

```
package com.example.test;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String finall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String FILENAME = "hello_file.txt";
        String string = "1234";

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try
        {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        try
        {
            FileInputStream in = openFileInput("hello_file.txt");
            StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

            while(in.read(buffer) != -1)
            {
                fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
            }
            finall = fileContent.toString();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText(finall);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendGo(v);

            }
        });
    }

    public void sendGo(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The first part work because i can read my saved file in the same activity.
But when i try to read it into another activity, it does'nt work:

```
package com.example.test;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    String finall="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        try
        {
            FileInputStream in = openFileInput("hello_file.txt");
            StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

            while(in.read(buffer) != -1)
            {
                fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
            }
            finall = fileContent.toString();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mehmet);
        text.setText(finall);
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your logcat data

Comment: I think you should use startActivityForResult instead startActivity..
anyway, post your logcat, it will help us to see what cause the application to crash

Comment: make sure u have declared `SecondActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: @StinePike How can i share my logcat? i send you an image (imp. screen) of it?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yeah i have done it!  <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.test.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.test.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want share data between activities, you can do :

1. Intent and put extra data in the Bundle
2. SharePreferences (You can access it even when application is closed & relaunched again)
3. SqLite database (You can access it even when application is closed & relaunched again)
4. Static Class

This is how you can use SharedPrefs ->

```
SharedPreferences pref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("KEY_PASSORD", "Password to Save");
editor.commit();
```

And when you want to retrieve the password from SharedPrefs do this ->

```
SharedPreferences Pref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
String password = pref.getString("KEY_PASSWORD","Default Password");
```

Comment: It's not only to share data between activities but in the same time to save this data. Because here, i try to save a password...

Comment: Okay thank you but what i show is only a test, because my target is to create a login page where the user enter only a password (not an username). And in this mainactivity, i add a button to change his password. So i would like to recover this new password in a new activity & change the old password which is in the MainActivity..

Comment: Yes that should be fine...If you recover/reset password in new activity & want to get same password in mainactivity, then both will be same as prefs as maintained for application context

Comment: Yeah, can you help me with some ideas but i try it previously but it does'nt work. After that, i tried it with File, etc. If you have any idea for me, it will be very cool from you :)

Comment: Okay...I'll post the related code on github and will give you the URL on tomorrow

Comment: thank you very very much :) because i do it in my internship, it's very important for me who is new in android area. I try it since 3-4 days, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I know for passing variable between activity is the following:

In your Activity you create a new Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("nameofvariable","valueofvariable");
startActivity(intent);
```

And from next Activity you can retrieve this value in this way:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("nameofvariable");
}
```

however, the correct way for using FileInputStream is this:

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("hello_file.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but when you use putExtra for an intent, this variable is not saved. Here, i try to save the password & show it an another activity. I try with SharedPrefences but it doesn't work too.. I will try your second solution, i come back ;)

Comment: @forgive90 post your error. Edit your question, and attach it on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If you want share data between activities, you can use :

- Intent and put extra data in the Bundle
- SharePreferences in the Application class
- SQLite database
- Static variable

Answer (score 0):

I tested your app on emulator (level 8) and on Samsung galaxy S3 (level 16) and it works fine!

The textView of the 2nd activity is 1234.

You test on which devices?

And could you send us you logcat log?

Don't miss to declare all activities in your AndroiManifest.xml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePreferences in first activty and save your password into it:

```
package com.example.test;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor editor;

private final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText(finall);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pref  = getSharedPreferences("passwordPref", 0); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD ,YourEditBox.getText());
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

}
```

And in the second activty use this for retrieving your password:

```
package com.example.test;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor editor;

private final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("passwordPref", 0);
    YourEditText.setText(pref.getString(KEY_PASSWORD,""));
}

}
```

Comment: Hi my friend, i will try your code, but can you edit your answer in my previous code please? thank you very much