# pass listview values from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I have one list view and there are different values within it such as name, qty,unit,disc,price. I want to pass these values to next activity. I set 5 text boxes in new activity. this new activity is for update the values. how to pass values and display the same in new activity.???

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Update.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("ItemName", "value");
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Show the code....what you have done???

Comment: add your code also

Comment: Asked so much times. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16510667/1584654

If you want pass the entire object instead of the single field, you need that your object implements Parcelable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save my value in one activity and show this value into different activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510517/save-my-value-in-one-activity-and-show-this-value-into-different-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following ways for sharing data in android:

- Intent and put extra data in the Bundle
- SharePreferences in the Application class
- SQLite database
- Static variable

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data via Intent Extras eg :-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,calledActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Caller",THIS_ACTIVITY);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In this example Caller is the Key and THIS_ACTIVITY contains the value to be passed. This is then retrieved in the called activity like :-

```
    String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an entire object through `Intents`, as long as they implement the `Parcelable` / `Serializable class`.

```
public class Myclass implements Parcelable {}
```

Implementing these classes will ensure that your Object can be serialized.
Then you will be able to attach it to your `Intent`, and later retrieve it by calling `getParcelableExtra` or other methods.